# How do I flip along the axis using web version of Sketchup?

Tags: sketchup

It seems straight forward.

Select your object, right click and select `Flip Along`.

However this does nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to report that I cannot confirm your trouble, as when I tried web SketchUp, entered into Component Edit mode, and chose **Flip Along>Green Direction** I got the expected result.

[image]

Note that I demonstrate in my screencap that when the component was symmetric along that component, you couldn't *tell* it had been flipped... once I added a small plate at one corner, ***then*** you could ***see*** the component flip along its axis.

Note also that this operation (Flip Along Component's own axis) will *never* ***translate*** the component in the *world* axis space - it maintains the same world position and flips relative to its own centrepoint and exterior bounds.

Hope that helps.

---

EDIT to address comment:

Of course you can translate your mesh any way you'd expect: scale, rotate, move... you need to use the translate tools to accomplish this kind of task. As you see in this super-quick screencap, when you long-click on the Move tool, you see all three translate tools: Move, Rotate, and Scale. Each does as the name suggests.

[image]

I will point out that though they're re-organised for the web app, and there are only a subset of the main tools available compared to SketchUp Pro or even SketchUp Make, the ones which are present do function as expected, and though it's a bit clunky having to long-press to get related tools, it's still a very intuitive approach to modeling for 3D novices.

From here I think it best that I advise you to look through the online documentation, including their tutorial videos - spend the half to three quarters of an hour looking through these things that it should take you - and save yourself *hours* of later hassle and confusion by investing in that comprehension time up front!

Comment: I added a marker on my component and can see that it is now flipping along it's own axis.  Is there a way to make it rotate in the environment.  I want to add it to the face of my prism.